# Find changed variable/field name in aura:valueChange event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

When using

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.state}" action="{!c.changed}"/>
```

I can see field go from old value to new one (event.getParam('oldValue')), but I cannot see which field it actually changed, making it not very useful :|

Is there a way to get field without doing component.get() ?

Comment: Nope. If you're writing code that depends on knowing the field that changed, you'll have to take responsibility for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this somewhat later, but I thought I'd respond.
There is a undocumented parameter *expression* that returns the name of the data object name (not the input name or id):

```
console.log("changed: " + event.getParam("expression") + " " + event.getParam("oldValue") + " -> " + event.getParam("value"));

Results in: 
changed: v.leadInfo.lastName Last N -> Last Na
```

The change handler can be used to show or hide elements when a value changes from blank to a value (or the other way around) using $A.util.removeClass/addClass, or to run a form validation method.

Here's an example of my helper that does these things (it's an input form for a wrapperClass):

```
({
    init : function(component) { 
    },
    onLeadInfoChange: function(component, event) {  
        // INITIAL LOAD
        if (!component.get("v.leadInfoOrg")) { 
            var lead = component.get("v.leadInfo");

            // store initial object for possible reset  
            var leadOrg = Object.assign({}, lead); // clone
            component.set("v.leadInfoOrg", leadOrg);
        }

        this.validateForm(component);

        // set initial hidden/visible fields            
        if (event.getParam("expression").endsWith("leadInfo")) {
            this.toggleField(component, "account", component.get("v.leadInfo.accountName"));
            this.toggleField(component, "contact", component.get("v.leadInfo.lastName"));
        }
        if (event.getParam("expression").endsWith("accountName")) {
            this.toggleFieldwithOld(component, "account", event.getParam("value"), event.getParam("oldValue"));
        }
        if (event.getParam("expression").endsWith("lastName")) {
            this.toggleFieldwithOld(component, "contact", event.getParam("value"), event.getParam("oldValue"));
        }
        //console.log("MF_LeadForm.onLeadInfoChange: " + event.getParam("expression") + " " + event.getParam("oldValue") + " -> " + event.getParam("value"));     
    },
    showForm: function(component, show) {
        component.set("v.showForm", show);      
    },
    resetForm: function(component) {
        component.set("v.leadInfo", component.get("v.leadInfoOrg")); 
    },  
    submitForm: function(component, event, handler){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 

        // form is valid; updating Org and hide form
        var leadOrg = Object.assign({}, component.get("v.leadInfo")); // clone
        component.set("v.leadInfoOrg", leadOrg);                
        this.showForm(component, false);
    },  
    validateForm: function(component) {
        var fields=["accountName", "billingStreet", "billingPostalCode", "billingCity", "salutation", "firstName", "lastName", "contactPhone", "accountPhone", "email"]; 
        var field = ""; 
        var validity = null;

        for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) { 
            field=component.find(fields[i]); 
            validity=field.get('v.validity'); 
            if (typeof validity == 'object' && validity != null) { 
                if (!validity.valid){
                    component.set("v.validity", false);
                    console.log(fields[i]+': invalid.');
                    return;
                } 
            } 
        } 
        component.set("v.validity", true);
    },  
    toggleField: function(component, name, value) {     
        if (value) {
            this.showField(component, name);
        } else if (!value) {
            this.hideField(component, name);
        }        
    },
    toggleFieldwithOld: function(component, name, value, oldValue) {        
        if (value && !oldValue) {
            this.showField(component, name);
        } else if (!value && oldValue) {
            this.hideField(component, name);
        }        
    },
    hideField: function(component, name) {      
        $A.util.addClass(component.find(name), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("no-" + name), "slds-hide");
    },
    showField: function(component, name) {
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find(name), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("no-" + name), "slds-hide");
    }
})
```

Comment: Very nice! Of course need to be vary of using undocumented features :) How did you find it btw?

Comment: Great find with event.getParam("expression").  It's still working June 2018.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
onInputValueChange: function(component, event) {  

    // If using lightning:inputField
    let fieldName = event.getSource().get('v.fieldName');

    // If using lightning:input, assign the field name as 'name' to the input component.
    let fieldName = event.getSource().get('v.name');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **aura:valueChange**

Ref Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm

So there is an event which will get fired when the value of attribute is changed, but there is **no such way to get the old value**, that you need to maintain by writing some logic which will set the old data in an attribute on load... something like that..

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to say. I am using that event, it **does** have an old value and what I _actually_ need is a way to know which field in an object changed.